# to interpret open interest

Tags: options, open-interest

I am interested to ask about how to interpret option open interest. For small cap stock options, it makes sense to see open interest as liquidity.

On the other hand, for big name stock options where liquidity is not really a concern, open interest seem better to be interpreted as a measure of attention. wonder how these option signals would do if controlled open interest

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "these option signals"?

Comment: things like skews,